# How do I connect to the Bluetooth icon in preferences or applications

Tags: bluetooth

My mouse is working great on Bluetooth, but I have tried without success to get anything else to work. I am trying to connect my FitBit.

I tried:

1. Shutting down in Preferences. When off, hold down shift/control/option and power button for 6 seconds. When it comes on, check preferences for the Bluetooth icon.
2. Going to system preferences, check View, then customize, but no Bluetooth to customize.
3. I used Disc Utility to repair my hard drive.
4. I noticed that in the system report when Bluetooth was clicked, it said no information.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  Have you talked with FitBit support and asked how to get their product to pair?

Comment: This sounds like you’re trying to pair your Fitbit to your Mac *computer*.  Is this the case?